# Can you limit the number of processes N|Solid uses?

Tags: node.js, nsolid

Is there is a way to limit the number of processes(in a single cluster on a single machine) that N|Solid can start?

Comment: You need to limit the quantity of child processes or the maximum number of processes deployed in a single cluster?

Comment: I was thinking the processes deployed in a single cluster.  For example, we're starting with internal apps which have very low traffic, and 2 processes is plenty....in testing on my Mac, it started with 20+ processes and the fan was at full blast, but then it settled down to ~5 processes.  Obviously this was a quick test following the docs, so I might not have it configured correctly.

Comment: Can someone explain the -1 vote?  NSolid lists this as their forum, where is the proper place for this question, or how should it be rephrased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cluster` module generally should use one child process per core, though that depends external factors, such as what else the system is doing. A spin up of 20 processes sounds like an issue, looks like cluster code is failing the master check and start masters and children.

We can use all nsolid built-in tools to debug your implementation/configuration. Please let us know

Comment: Thank you.  I will give it another run with a fresh install and contact you if see the same behavior.